# Can we get image data of the transformed image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am applying perspective transformation onto a canvas image. But as per the documentation, the getImageData() is not affected by the transformation matrix. The canvas data that I am transforming is an in-memory canvas so
I don't think tricks on the DOM elements would work out.

Is there any way in javascript to get the image data of the transformed image using canvas (or anything else) or basically apply the mathematics of CSS transform to canvas/image data?

Comment: Are the perspective transformations applied in CSS? If so, is the problem how to apply them to image data without CSS?

Comment: @traktor53..yes they are applied in CSS since mostly because I want to do this in the browser.

Comment: @traktor53...i think yes then the problem reduces to applying the transformation to image data.

Comment: I suggest updating the question with more details of what you want to achieve. While taking a screen shot of part of the web page might be a solution, so might reproducing the mathematics of the CSS transform on canvas data.

Comment: @traktor53, Taking a screenshot of the web page is not a solution in my case since this is a in-memory canvas. I ll update this in the question. Reproducing mathematics of CSS transform on canvas data is the problem.